# white-space: nowrap; Causes grid-item to expand

Tags: html, css

My issue is that adding `white-space: nowrap;` to any of my classes, this causes my .grid-item to expand.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 200px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item-text-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.grid-item-text-link:hover {
  color: Highlight
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex container-md justify-content-center">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <a href="/adventures of huckleberry finn"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/panmac/tr:f-auto,di-placeholder_portrait_aMjPtD9YZ.jpg,w-270/edition/9781509827992.jpg" height="141" width="85"></a>
      <br>
      <a class="grid-item-text-link" href="/adventures of huckleberry finn">Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JackFordTrY/pen/WNgObdq).

How can I prevent this behaviour, so that I can use text-overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason was that you need to set the **width** or **max-width** of the element to make **text-overflow** + **white-space** work.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 200px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: black;
}

.grid-item-text-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.grid-item-text-link:hover {
  color: Highlight;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex container-md justify-content-center">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <a href="/adventures of huckleberry finn"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/panmac/tr:f-auto,di-placeholder_portrait_aMjPtD9YZ.jpg,w-270/edition/9781509827992.jpg" height="141" width="85"></a>
      <br>
      <a class="grid-item-text-link" href="/adventures of huckleberry finn">Adventures of Huckleberry Finn long text here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```